# Where to find the phone number assigned to a MS Teams user?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams

The /users resource in MS Teams Graph API does not provide the phone number set using https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/getting-phone-numbers-for-your-users. It just provides business phone, fax, and mobile numbers but not the actual phone number that can be used to call it. Does anyone know if there's an endpoint that provides that detail?

Thanks!

Comment: Currently GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users provides businessPhones, faxNumber, mobilePhone, mail, which is already coming according to you. So what is meant by actual phone number. Could you elaborate?

Comment: Hello, sorry for not being clear. The "actual phone number" that I am referring to is the one assigned to a user so they can make and receive phone calls. The way to assign it is documented here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/assign-change-or-remove-a-phone-number-for-a-user.

Comment: After digging, I was able to get the voice phone numbers through Teams Powershell cmdlet Get-CSOnlineTelephoneNumber provided that I have admin credentials. Is there a way to get those without requiring admin credentials?

Comment: We are trying to repro your scenario. Will let you know soon.

Comment: Hello, any updates on this? Thanks a lot.

Comment: @joyce - Could you Please check answer posted below.

Comment: Hello, yes, enabling admin credentials to my MS account allows me to query the voice phone numbers. Was hoping there's another way we could query those without requiring admin credentials but if there isn't, that's fine. Thanks.

Comment: Did anyone find a way to do this through Graph?

Comment: Looks like there isn't a way to get it through Graph. Can be done via Teams Powershell(if you have admin creds) only at the moment.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You need SFB admin credentials to retrieve telephone numbers of users in your tenant.

Thank You.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Yeah, I already have an admin acct so I can retrieve the telephone numbers already. Was hoping that there's a way for me to retrieve those through powershell without the need to have total admin permissions.