# Microsoft Graph API to read phone number assigned to Teams user

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams

Is there any MS Graph API to read phone number assigned to Teams user for Direct Routing?

Answer (score 2):

Please go through [Get a user](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-get?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http). It returns a default set of properties businessPhones, displayName, givenName, id, mobilePhone, officeLocation etc.

Edit :
Please go through [Get-CsOnlineTelephoneNumber](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/skype/get-csonlinetelephonenumber?view=skype-ps) to retrieve telephone numbers from the Business Voice Directory. Similar question was asked in this [Where to find the phone number assigned to a MS Teams user?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66324837/where-to-find-the-phone-number-assigned-to-a-ms-teams-user)

Comment: Yeah, I know. But, i need to get the phone number assigned to user through Teams admin for direct routing (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/assign-change-or-remove-a-phone-number-for-a-user).?

Comment: This can be done using powershell. Please go through [Get-CsOnlineTelephoneNumber](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/skype/get-csonlinetelephonenumber?view=skype-ps) to retrieve telephone numbers from the Business Voice Directory. Similar question was asked in this [Where to find the phone number assigned to a MS Teams user?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66324837/where-to-find-the-phone-number-assigned-to-a-ms-teams-user)

Comment: Hi @Meghana-MSFT , I couldnt get the direct routing phone number using getUser api. It seems like only it can be read from microsoft power shell. For a project requirement, I need to get the phone number of a user from ASP.Net code by passing userid or name. Can you please suggest a way to achieve this?

Comment: @Priya - This can be done using powershell. Please go through [Get-CsOnlineTelephoneNumber](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/skype/get-csonlinetelephonenumber?view=skype-ps) to retrieve telephone numbers from the Business Voice Directory. Similar question was asked in this [Where to find the phone number assigned to a MS Teams user?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66324837/where-to-find-the-phone-number-assigned-to-a-ms-teams-user)

Comment: Hi @Meghana-MSFT, I am able to get the direct routing phone number assigned to user in powershell with admin credentials. Thats not an issue. 1) My question is there any **graph api** to read the direct routing phone number assigned to user? or else 2) My application gets an msal token generated with user account credentials for api access. is there any way to read this phone number in C# code using the user token (not with admin account credentials)?

Comment: There is no Graph API to read the phone number assigned to user through Teams admin for direct routing. You can suggest this feature on [Microsoft Uservoice](https://feedbackportal.microsoft.com/feedback/forum/ad198462-1c1c-ec11-b6e7-0022481f8472).