# Sync MS Teams user Phone Number to Active Directory

Tags: active-directory, microsoft-graph-teams, microsoft-graph-api

I want to access the `Phone Number` assigned to a user in the MS Teams using the `Graph API`.
I see the Graph API `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/teams/{ID}/members` returns all the Teams members but without the user `Phone Number` field.

Referring to other questions, we can not retrieve the Phone number using the Graph APIs.
[Microsoft Graph API to read phone number assigned to Teams user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70198521/microsoft-graph-api-to-read-phone-number-assigned-to-teams-user)

We can only do that using the PowerShell command `Get-CsOnlineTelephoneNumber`.

So, is there a way we can Sync the Teams user's `Phone Number` to Active Directory user's `Business Phone Number`?
So that it can be read using the Graph API `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users?$select=businessPhones`?

Answer (score 0):

You are correct that to grab the phone number (also known as LineURI) the current only way of grabbing it programatically is via pwsh today with the Teams Powershell Module.

To Sync back down to AD (ex. to telephoneNumber attribute) , you would also need to use the AD module for powershell.

There's a blog post here with a sample script that shows how to do it all:
https://goziro.com/how-to-sync-microsoft-teams-phone-numbers-with-active-directory/